# How do I add a simple image overlay in Mapbox Javascript?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

The following link in the Mapbox Javascript API describes how to add an image overlay on a map, and it is very simple :

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/

This works! However, I am trying to add an image overlay on a custom map. I am wanting to do this without creating tiles or anything of the like.

I can't find a way to overlay an image on a satellite map (that's my goal, just a weather radar GIF on a satellite map), but I can't seem to get this to work on any other map besides the one in the link above! How do I do this? I don't want the map they are using in their example. I just would like to overlay this on any custom map without needless complexity as they have in their example. Thank you for any help.

EDIT : This is the code - I tried to change it after a comment here but I still am doing something wrong.

```
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.44.2/mapbox-gl.css' 
rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>

<div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>


<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 
'pk.eyJ1IjoiZm9ybXVsYTQiLCJhIjoiY2lzNWl5N3RpMDNhYTNvcDFvNGVrZmZheCJ9.2X- 
n4Yk2XyxYqoPbP_IMnQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
zoom: 4,
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
center: [-80.425, 37.437]
});



map.addSource("myImageSource", {"type": "image",
"url": "radar.gif",
"coordinates": [
[-80.425, 46.437],
[-71.516, 46.437],
[-71.516, 37.936],
[-80.425, 37.936]
]})



map.addLayer({
"id": "overlay",
"source": "myImageSource",
"type": "raster",
"paint": {"raster-opacity": 0.85}
})



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: I have edited it. I don't know what to do at this point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*My edits to the helpfull existing answer were not accepted, so posting this in an own answer.*

You have to wait until the style is done loading before adding the image source and layer. The following code is working:

Please note:
If you are storing the `HTML` and the `GIF` file locally, maybe the `GIF` is not displayed because of some browser restrictions. You may try the Firefox browser which is less strict than Chrome in this regard.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add an image</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZm9ybXVsYTQiLCJhIjoiY2lzNWl5N3RpMDNhYTNvcDFvNGVrZmZheCJ9.2X-n4Yk2XyxYqoPbP_IMnQ';


        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            maxZoom: 5.99,
            minZoom: 4,
            zoom: 5,
            center: [-75.789, 41.874],
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9'
        });

        map.on('load', function() {
            map.addSource("myImageSource", {
                "type": "image",
                "url": "radar.gif",
                "coordinates": [
                    [-80.425, 46.437],
                    [-71.516, 46.437],
                    [-71.516, 37.936],
                    [-80.425, 37.936]
                ]
            });

            map.addLayer({
                "id": "overlay",
                "source": "myImageSource",
                "type": "raster",
                "paint": {
                "raster-opacity": 0.85
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: example]

Comment: Wow, thank you! This was my first question on stack overflow and I wasnt sure if anyone could even help me but it was worth a try. I will now be able to look at the code and learn from it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm having trouble - Got this to work, but I want to add my own style that I created myself in mapbox, such as:

style: 'mapbox://styles/nittyjee.duzurkuo

Answer (score 1):

They are adding both a custom layer and the basemap in the same JSON. However you can add your image separatly.

First add a [source with your image](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#imagesource):

```
mapBoxMap.addSource("myImageSource", {"type": "image",
    "url": "/mapbox-gl-js/assets/radar.gif",
     "coordinates": [
        [-80.425, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 37.936],
        [-80.425, 37.936]
     ]})
```

Then [add a layer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addlayer) displaying this source:

```
mapBoxMap.addLayer({
  "id": "overlay",
  "source": "myImageSource",
  "type": "raster",
  "paint": {"raster-opacity": 0.85}
})
```

In Mapbox GL, basemaps and custom layers are technically the same thing.

Comment: It is still not working. I am not sure what is going on. Here is the code, which is not very much but it just doesn't display the image: