# How to add image from mobile storage to mapbox-gl?

Tags: vue.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, ionic5

I've been trying to add an image overlay to mapbox-gl-js on a project that uses Ionic 5 + Vue.js, similar to what [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#imageoverlay) does, but i cannot get it to work.

The only way that I can get it to work is by following [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image-generated/) tutorial, but the image does not fit properly into the polygon. I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50878130/5124600), and I can see when Capacitor requests the image, but it does not load. It works fine on Chrome, but on mobile it does not.

This is the code that I have now:

```
  const { map } = this;
  if (map.getLayer(layerId)) {
    map.removeLayer(layerId);
  }
  if (map.getSource(sourceId)) {
    map.removeSource(sourceId);
  }
  map.addSource(sourceId, { ...source, url: Capacitor.convertFileSrc(source.url) });
  map.addLayer(layer);
```

whereas the source and layer objects are like this:

```
  const sourceId = `${talhao.id}-image`;
  const layerId = `${talhao.id}-image-${image.id}`;
  const bbox = getBoundingBox(talhao);
  const source = {
    type: "image",
    url: image.imagemPng,
    coordinates: [
      bbox.getNorthWest().toArray(),
      bbox.getNorthEast().toArray(),
      bbox.getSouthEast().toArray(),
      bbox.getSouthWest().toArray()
    ]
  };

  const layer = {
    id: layerId,
    source: sourceId,
    type: "raster",
    paint: {
      "raster-opacity": 0.85
    }
  };
```

Any help would be appreciated!

edit: It is worth noticing that I do not think that the image is the problem here, because I use the same image in another part of the screen that I'm working and it loads fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the mapbox-gl-js library had a bug in version 1.x that prevented the image from showing on mobile.

Upgraded to version 2.0.1 and it worked.